# How to determine an Increase in Employee Salary from consecutive Contract Rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I got a problem in my query :

My table store data like this

```
ContractID | Staff_ID | EffectDate  | End Date   | Salary | active
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          | 1        | 2013-01-01  | 2013-12-30 | 100    | 0
2          | 1        | 2014-01-01  | 2014-12-30 | 150    | 0
3          | 1        | 2015-01-01  | 2015-12-30 | 200    | 1
4          | 2        | 2014-05-01  | 2015-04-30 | 500    | 0
5          | 2        | 2015-05-01  | 2016-04-30 | 700    | 1
```

I would like to write a query like below:

```
ContractID | Staff_ID | EffectDate  | End Date   | Salary | Increase
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          | 1        | 2013-01-01  | 2013-12-30 | 100    | 0
2          | 1        | 2014-01-01  | 2014-12-30 | 150    | 50
3          | 1        | 2015-01-01  | 2015-12-30 | 200    | 50
4          | 2        | 2014-05-01  | 2015-04-30 | 500    | 0
5          | 2        | 2015-05-01  | 2016-04-30 | 700    | 200  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Increase column is calculated by current contract minus previous contract

I use sql server 2008 R2

Comment: What is **contract** column ?

Comment: ContractID is the primary key of Contract Table. It is an identity column

Comment: the main purpose of this query is : to know the amount of salary increase of all staff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately 2008R2 doesn't have access to `LAG`, but you can simulate the effect of obtaining the previous row (`prev`) in the scope of a current row (`cur`), with a RANKing and a self join to the previous ranked row, in the same partition by Staff_ID):

```
With CTE AS 
(
    SELECT [ContractID], [Staff_ID], [EffectDate], [End Date], [Salary],[active], 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY Staff_ID ORDER BY ContractID) AS Rnk
    FROM Table1
)
SELECT cur.[ContractID], cur.[Staff_ID], cur.[EffectDate], cur.[End Date],
    cur.[Salary], cur.Rnk,
    CASE WHEN (cur.Rnk = 1) THEN 0 -- i.e. baseline salary
         ELSE cur.Salary - prev.Salary END AS Increase
FROM CTE cur
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE prev
    ON cur.[Staff_ID] = prev.Staff_ID and cur.Rnk - 1 = prev.Rnk;
```

(If ContractId is always perfectly incrementing, we wouldn't need the `ROW_NUMBER` and could join on incrementing ContractIds, I didn't want to make this assumption).

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5ea990/1)

**Edit**

If you have Sql 2012 and later, the [LEAD and LAG Analytic Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) make this kind of query much simpler:

```
SELECT [ContractID], [Staff_ID], [EffectDate], [End Date], [Salary], 
Salary - LAG(Salary, 1, Salary) OVER (Partition BY Staff_ID ORDER BY ContractID) AS Incr
FROM Table1
```

[Updated SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5ea990/2)

One trick here is that we are calculating delta increments in salary, so for the first employee contract we need to return the current salary so that `Salary - Salary = 0` for the first increase.